# EncryptingJsonConvertor in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I tried using the solution of encrypting some properties of my class in JSON mentioned by [Thomas Freudenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196809/how-can-i-encrypt-selected-properties-when-serializing-my-objects). When I serialize the object using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` I get the desired result.

The class and convertor are located in a separate assembly, which is referenced in my WebAPI project. When I use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ApiUsers/List")]
public Dto.ApiUsersResponse List(Dto.ApiUsersRequest apiUsersRequest)
{
    IEnumerable<Db.ApiUser> dbApiUsers = GetList<Db.ApiUser>(StoredProcedures.GetApiUsers);

    return new Dto.ApiUsersResponse()
    {
         ApiUsers = dbApiUsers.Select(apiUser => new Dto.ApiUser()
         {
            ClientId = apiUser.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = apiUser.ClientSecret
         })
    };
}
```

the result is in clear text instead. The conversion never happens.

I have tried changing the controller's response IHttpActionResult and using `Ok()` and `Content()` but to no avail.

When I try to register the convertor using:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new EncryptingJsonConverter());
```

The error is:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonFormatter'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: so your this class EncryptingJsonConverter  and all models are in different project?

Comment: Yes, the convertor and the models are in a shared assembly.