# Implementing A Custom JSONConverter To Read/Save Data To A Separate File

Tags: vb.net, json.net, jsonconverter

I'm working on creating a JSON configuration file setup for my application. The application will require access to sensitive information (*specifically login credentials and decryption passwords*) Obviously, I'd rather not store this kind of sensitive data in the JSON as plain-text, so I've come up with what I *believe* is a decent solution. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong and there's a better solution, but this is what I've come to through my research so far.

What I'd *like* to do is something like what's available in .NET Core to store this data in a "protected" file (*stored in the user's `%appdata%` folder*). The idea is to allow the user to enter the sensitive data into the main configuration file, then implement a custom `JsonConverter` object to "move" it over to the protected file.

For example, I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "MyApplication": {
    "ApplicationHost": "localhost",
    "ManagedItems": [
      {
        "SiteID": "3b1c7e59-d7a0-4451-d8e3-169517ec1d6b",
        "Name": "MySite",
        "UserPassword": "My$3c?e7P@$sw0rD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, amongst the others, I have this `Property` in my class:

```vbnet
<JsonProperty("UserPassword")>
<JsonConverter(GetType(PasswordProtector))>
Public Property UserPassword As String
```

And, then I've started working on the `PasswordProtector` custom `JsonConverter` class as follows:

```vbnet
Public Class PasswordProtector
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        If TypeOf value Is ApplicationSettings.ManagedItem Then
            Dim BaseObject As JObject = CType(JToken.FromObject(value), JObject)
            Dim UserData As New UserDataSettings

            If UserDataFile.Exists Then
                Dim JSONData As String = File.ReadAllText(UserDataFile.FullName)

                UserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UserDataSettings)(JSONData)

                If UserData.MyApplication Is Nothing Then
                    UserData.MyApplication = New UserDataSettings.AppSettings
                End If

                If UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems Is Nothing Then
                    UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems = New List(Of UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem)

                    UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                        .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                        .UserPassword = BaseObject("UserPassword")})
                Else
                    If Not UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Where(Function(c) c.SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID")).First Is Nothing Then
                        UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Where(Function(c) c.SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID")).First.UserPassword = BaseObject("UserPassword")
                    Else
                        UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                            .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                            .UserPassword = BaseObject("UserPassword")})
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                UserData.MyApplication = New UserDataSettings.AppSettings
                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems = New List(Of UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem)
                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                    .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                    .UserPassword = BaseObject("UserPassword")})

            End If

            If Not UserDataFile.Directory.Exists Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(UserDataFile.DirectoryName)
            End If

            File.WriteAllText(UserDataFile.FullName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserData, JSONSettings))
            UserDataFile.Refresh()

            BaseObject("UserPassword") = "[PROTECTED]"
            serializer.Serialize(writer, BaseObject, GetType(ApplicationSettings.ManagedItem))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim BaseObject As JObject = JObject.Load(reader)

        If TypeOf existingValue Is ApplicationSettings.ManagedItem Then
            Dim UserData As New UserDataSettings
            Dim TargetItem As New ApplicationSettings.ManagedItem
            Dim UserPassword As String = Nothing

            If BaseObject("UserPassword") IsNot Nothing Then
                UserPassword = BaseObject("UserPassword").ToString
            End If

            If UserDataFile.Exists Then
                UserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UserDataSettings)(File.ReadAllText(UserDataFile.FullName))

                If UserData.MyApplication Is Nothing Then
                    UserData.MyApplication = New UserDataSettings.AppSettings
                End If

                If UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim SavedSite As UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem = UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Where(Function(c) c.SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID")).First

                    If SavedSite IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim SavedPassword As String = SavedSite.UserPassword

                        If UserPassword IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserPassword) Then
                            If SavedPassword IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SavedPassword) Then
                                If UserPassword <> "[PROTECTED]" Then
                                    If UserPassword <> SavedPassword Then
                                        UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Where(Function(c) c.SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID")).First.UserPassword = UserPassword
                                        TargetItem.UserPassword = UserPassword
                                    Else
                                        TargetItem.UserPassword = SavedPassword
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    TargetItem.UserPassword = SavedPassword
                                End If
                            Else
                                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Where(Function(c) c.SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID")).First.UserPassword = UserPassword
                                TargetItem.UserPassword = UserPassword
                            End If
                        ElseIf SavedPassword IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SavedPassword) Then
                            TargetItem.UserPassword = SavedPassword
                        End If
                    Else
                        If UserPassword IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserPassword) Then
                            If UserPassword <> "[PROTECTED]" Then
                                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems = New List(Of UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem)
                                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                                    .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                                    .UserPassword = UserPassword})
                                TargetItem.UserPassword = UserPassword
                            Else
                                TargetItem.UserPassword = Nothing
                            End If
                        Else
                            TargetItem.UserPassword = Nothing
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems = New List(Of UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem)
                    UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                    .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                    .UserPassword = UserPassword})
                End If
            Else
                UserData.MyApplication = New UserDataSettings.AppSettings
                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems = New List(Of UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem)
                UserData.MyApplication.ManagedItems.Add(New UserDataSettings.AppSettings.ManagedItem With {
                                                                    .SiteID = BaseObject("SiteID"),
                                                                    .UserPassword = UserPassword})
            End If

            File.WriteAllText(UserDataFile.FullName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserData, JSONSettings))
            UserDataFile.Refresh()

            serializer.Populate(BaseObject.CreateReader(), TargetItem)
            Return TargetItem
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return GetType(ApplicationSettings.ManagedItem).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
    End Function
End Class
```

The idea is to have it put the `UserPassword` into a similar (but simplified) version of the same JSON structure in the "protected" file:

```json
{
  "ProtectedSettings": {
    "ManagedItems": [
      {
        "SiteID": "3b1c7e59-d7a0-4451-d8e3-169517ec1d6b",
        "UserPassword": "My$3c?e7P@$sw0rD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then replace/obfuscate the value in the "main" JSON file with `[PROTECTED]`. When the application loads the current configuration, it should pull the `UserPassword` from the protected file for use as required, but it should never rewrite anything but the obfuscated version (or `Nothing`) to the main file.

If the value in the main file is not `[PROTECTED]` (*meaning the user has changed it*), then it should update the protected file with that value and re-obfuscate the value in the main file.

I know there are *several* issues with my code so far. However, my *first* hurdle is getting it past the `ReadJson()` method. Whenever I try to execute `JObject.Load(reader)`, I get an exception:

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String.
```

I've tried casting the reader to an object, using the `JObject.Parse` on both the `reader.Path` and `reader.ReadAsString` (*the latter moves the reader to the next node, so that obviously won't work*), and a variety of other methods to get it to read the current value of the `UserPassword` object, but I can't seem to get past that so far.

Also, I wrote the entire method before I got around to doing any testing so, now that I'm trying to run things, I realize that the next line - `If TypeOf existingValue Is CertifySettings.ManagedCertificate` - isn't going to work either, but I'm taking things one step at a time here. I'm just providing the entirety of my code here to give a "big-picture" view of what I'm trying to do and how I *believe* it should work.

Am I just "spinning my wheels" here trying to make this work? Is there a better way to achieve my stated goals (*e.g., some other method of "moving" the sensitive data to a separate file and replacing/obfuscating it in the main config file*) other than using a `JsonConverter`? I need for my application to be able to access the sensitive information, but I just can't figure out the best way to keep it from being accessed by the casual observer. I've looked at several other implementations of custom `JsonConverter`s, but none of them quite seem to fit the use case closely enough for me to get from there to where I need to be.

Comment: Use `JToken.Load(reader)` if the current token might not be an object.  See [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Possibly [Using Json.NET, how can I encrypt selected properties of any type when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67109653/3744182) and/or [How can I encrypt selected properties when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809/3744182) may be useful as alternate approaches.  But I'm not a security professional so I can't really offer an opinion on whether your approach or the approaches from those questions are actually secure.

Comment: Thank you, @dbc. Those links may very well be helpful and I'll do some digging into the answers there. I had looked through several other posts, but my *Google-fu* apparently failed me. I'll come back and update my question if any of these suggestions get me closer to my goal.

Comment: As far as *Am I just "spinning my wheels" here trying to make this work?*, this seems opinion based and might be out of scope for stack overflow, where questions should have factual answers, and there should be [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: I apologize for the "rambling" nature of the post and perhaps making it too much of an opinion-based question. If I'm unable to refine the question to something more suitable, I will delete it.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I believe the answer to the *"Am I just "spinning my wheels"* part of my question is, unfortunately, going to be an emphatic "yes" - at least with the `JsonConverter` method. I have some other ideas about adding methods I can call from the constructor, but there are apparently some limitations that will prevent me from achieving this specific goal. Primarily, the inability to access other properties of the JSON object during Serialization/Deserialization means I can't set up a "meaningful" link between the two files.